# PHP foreach overwriting results Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, json, foreach, joomla2.5

I Everyone I am currently creating a component for Joomla 2.5 that uses jvectormap, and for some reason i am getting all of the continents and countries in a json but only the latest added firms and not the older ones... i think it may be to do with my foreach statement... But not really sure in all honesty:

my model file:

```
public function getLand()
{
$land_id = JRequest::getInt('id');

$db = $this->getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('*, a.continent_name,continent_facts');
$query->from('#__vectormap_countries AS t')
        ->join('LEFT', '#__vectormap_continents AS a USING(continent_id)')
        ->where('t.published = 1');

$db->setQuery($query);

$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

return $rows;
}

public function getFirm(){
    $firm_id = JRequest::getInt('id');

    $db = $this->getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select('*');
    $query->from('#__vectormap_firms AS t')
            ->where('t.published = 1');

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $firms = $db->loadObjectList();

    return $firms;
}
```

and then the part that is echo'ing the array my view.json.php:

```
public function display($tpl = null)
{
$land = $this->get('Land');
$firm = $this->get('Firm');
$response = array();

foreach ($land as $row) {
        $response[$row->country_code] = array(
                    'path' => $row->country_svgpath,
                    'name' => $row->country_name,
                    'continent' => $row->continent_name,
                    'fact' => $row->continent_facts
        );
};

foreach ($firm as $firms) {
        $response['firms'] = array (
            'firm_name' => $firms->firm_companyname,
            'firm_latitude' => $firms->firm_latitude,
            'firm_longitude' => $firms->firm_longitude
            );
        };
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

and that returns everything in the first foreach but in the second foreach it only returns the latest firm not all of them..

Please don't hesitate to ask if further detail is required.. Any Help Greatly Apreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the second loop to:

```
$response['firms'] = array();
foreach ($firm as $firms) {
        $response['firms'][] = array (
            'firm_name' => $firms->firm_companyname,
            'firm_latitude' => $firms->firm_latitude,
            'firm_longitude' => $firms->firm_longitude
            );
        };
```

With this, `$response['firms']` will be an indexed array listing all the firms.

Answer (score 0):

The key in the second foreach is fixed, as `$response['firms']`, so later runs will over-write earlier ones. You can try something like this:

```
foreach ($firm as $firms) {
    $response[$firms->firm_companyname] = array (
        'firm_latitude' => $firms->firm_latitude,
        'firm_longitude' => $firms->firm_longitude
        );
    };
```

Which will give you the company name as a key - you need something that's going to change on each run of the loop. You could also have an incrementing integer:

```
$firmcount = 0;
foreach ($firm as $firms) {
    $response['firms' . $firmcount++] = array (
        'firm_name' => $firms->firm_companyname,
        'firm_latitude' => $firms->firm_latitude,
        'firm_longitude' => $firms->firm_longitude
        );
    };
```